# I would like to add one more conversation to actions.json

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, fulfillment

I have an application within watson assistant that consumes many services from other endpoints. and I would like to call this conversation (from watson) within a google assistant conversation in a certain intention. for example i will develop a rich conversation on google assistant and in one of the options i will call watson's conversation.
I tried as follows, but it didn't work. does anyone know any example that can help me?

```
{"locale": "pt-BR",
 "actions": [
   {
     "description": "Launch intent",
     "name": "MAIN",
     "fulfillment": {
       "conversationName": "mainConversation"
     },
     "intent": {
       "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
     }
   },
   {
    "description": "Direct access",
    "name": "BUY",
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "ExampleAction"
    },
    "intent": {
      "name": "com.example.ExampleAction.BUY",
      "trigger": {
        "queryPatterns": [
          "teste",
          "azul",
          "start"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 ],
 "conversations": {
   "mainConversation": {
     "name": "mainConversation",
     "url": "https://us-central1-ericanovo-798cc.cloudfunctions.net/webhook",
     "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
   },
   "BUY": {
    "name": "ExampleAction",
    "url": "https://orquestrador-sulamerica-teste.mybluemix.net/api/v1/chat/google?externaltoken=574213c0-e904-11e9-9970-ff484aa25334",
    "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
  }

 }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That won't work because the webhook for everything published under the same project has to be the same URL. You are expected to handle all the Intents and "actions" at that webhook.

In your case, you would also need to make sure the request is formatted the way the Watson API would be expecting it. The Assistant will send it using the [Conversation Webhook Format](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/build/json/conversation-webhook-json), and it sounds like you would send it using [Watson's Analyze Text](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding#analyze-text) API.

You're not showing any of your code, so it is difficult to be sure - but the first would be in a JSON format that you can extract. You can then use a library in Node (such as [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) to make the calls to Watson. Based on the result from Watson, you'd need to format the results as a response and return it to the Assistant.

It isn't clear why you'd need multiple webhooks specifically, although it is certainly possible that some Intents may make different API calls than others.

Keep in mind that your custom Intents will only be valid on invocation. Subsequent Intents will all be TEXT Intents.

Comment: do you know any way to call another webhook within an intention?

Comment: In one webhook, you can certainly call another, but it isn't clear why you want to do so. You may wish to update your question to make it more clear exactly why you feel you need to do so to see if we can help you find a better way to do what you want.

Comment: I did the editing of the question make sure it was clear please

Comment: Answer updated. Please don't use another answer to try and ask a question or get attention. Comments are the best way to do so.